# Is the following proof that every truth assignment in propositional logic is well-defined correct?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

A few lectures into a course on logic I found online the teacher defines a truth assignment $v:F\rightarrow \{ t,f\}$ (where $F$ is the set of all well-formed formulas and $t,f$ denote 'true'and 'false' respectively) such that for every $\alpha ,\beta \in F$ we have $v\big( (\neg \alpha)\big) =t$ if and only if $v(\alpha)=f$; $v\big((\alpha \wedge \beta )\big) = t$ if and only if $v(\alpha )=v(\beta )=t$; etc.

The teacher then sets out to prove that $v$ is well-defined, that is, if $\alpha = \beta$ then $v(\alpha )=v(\beta )$ using some previous lemmas. He was corrected a few times as he wrote the proof, which I found to be too complicated and maybe not valid, although maybe I just didn't understand it. **I was merely wondering if the following proof would work:**

---

Let $S=\{ \text{wffs} \ \alpha : \alpha=\beta\Rightarrow v(\alpha)=v(\beta)\}$. By definition of the set we have $$S\subseteq F$$
We show the opposite inclusion by generalized induction.
Base Case: let $\alpha$ be a single propositional variable, this is a wff and if $\alpha=\alpha'$ these must be the same propositional variable, implying $v(\alpha)=v(\alpha')$.

Induction Step: let $\alpha, \beta\in S$. These are wffs and by the induction hypothesis $v(\alpha), v(\beta)$ are well-defined and thus so is $v\big( (\alpha \wedge \beta)\big)$. Therefore $F\subseteq S$ as wanted.

Comment: But really with $\alpha=\beta$ do you mean that they are the same formula ? If so: $v(\alpha)=v(\alpha)$.

Comment: Yes, I do mean they are the same formula. But just as if we were to define a $f:a/b\rightarrow a+b$ it might be the case this functions is not well-defined, as it is the case since $1/2=2/4$ but $f(1/2)\neq f(2/4)$.

Comment: If a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ is not well-defined then it isn't a function, so I guess one could argue that the definition of $S$ already presupposes $f$ is a function (and thus well-defined) which is what we are trying to prove. I think the idea of the proof would still work though, namely by reinterpreting $f$ as a set of ordered pairs, where $(a,b)\in f$ if and only if $f(a)=b$, where $f$ is a function iff $(a,b)=(a,c)\Rightarrow b=c$. We could then express $S$ as $\{ \text{wffs}\ a : (a ,b)=(a,c)\Rightarrow b=c\}$, not assuming that $f$ is well-defined to begin with.